# cannot import dask_query package in Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, dask

> import dask_bigquery

in colab fails with error message:

Getting No Module named 'dask.layers'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your `ImportError` just now, but then this worked:

```
!pip install -U dask
!pip install dask_bigquery

# restart runtime at this point

import dask_bigquery
```

Comment: Yup that was the fix.  I executed `!python -m pip install dask[complete]` from Colab caused that ImportError.  `!pip install -U dask` and the command that I executed seemed similar but obviously they are not.  Thanks.  That was great!!!